# How to make find_package(OpenCV) results global?

Tags: opencv, cmake

I have the following project structure:

```
- CMakeLists.txt  // [1]
D Dependencies    
-- CMakeLists.txt // [2]
D MySubProject    
-- CMakeLists.txt // [3]
```

[1] is my main cmake-file where I define explicitly define a project with project(..) and add the directoires Dependencies and MySubProject with add_subdirectory(..).

[2] is a cmake-file where I don't explicitly create a project with project(..). Here I simply setup my dependencies, e.g. for OpenCV calling:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
```

[3] is a cmake-file where I explecitly define a subproject with project(..). This subproject links to the OpenCV dependency:

```
project(MySubProject)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(MySubProject main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MySubProject ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

The problem I have is that in [3] i cannot acces the results of [2], e.g. OpenCV_LIBS or OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS. If I add the following lines to [2]

```
set(OpenCV_LIBS ${OpenCV_LIBS} CACHE STRING "")
set(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} CACHE STRING "")
```

I am able to access them in [3] but the contents of OpenCV_LIBS look like

```
opencv_world.lib
```

This doesn't work for my setup with OpenCV 3.0 and MSVC 11 2012. The library name is missing the version suffix. If I call the find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED) command in [3] directly, the OpenCV_LIBS looks correct, i.e.:

```
opencv_world330.lib
```

How can I achieve that I get the correct suffix for my OpenCV_LIBS when I call find_package(..) in [2] and make the resulting variables global by setting them in the cache?

Comment: In other words, set of variables, affected by `find_package()` call, depends from directory, where this call occures, doesn't it? Looks strange. Is content of `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS` also changed? Is OpenCV installed *outside* of the project?

Comment: You can pass the CMakeCache.txt file to the CMake run of your other project by adding -C. This might be a workaround.

Comment: @Tsyvarev no, not exactly. I got the impression that not the directory but the contents of the CMakeLists.txt have an influence. If it contains a project and a target definition the find_package command behaves different than in the case of a CMakeLists.txt which contains only find_* commands. The content of OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS isn't changed by the way. I use the downloadable binary version for Windows x64.

Comment: @usr1234567 although I don't like to make use of workarounds, thanks for that tip! Maybe I follow a wrong strategy, but isn't it a better way to centralize the find_package calls in a greater project instead of making one and the same find_package call in every subproject which uses the same dependency?

Comment: `isn't it a better way to centralize the find_package calls in a greater project` - Yes, actually this would be the best choice. If you want to organize all dependencies into own file, you may have this file included via `include()` (in the top-level `CMakeLists.txt`). Unlike to `add_subdirectory()`, `include()` doesn't introduce new variable's scope, so all variables set by `find_package()` will be globally visible by your project.

Comment: @Tsyvarev a big thank you - your hint solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I replace the line

```
add_subdirectory(Dependencies)
```

of [1] with

```
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/CMakeLists.txt)
```

the results of all find_* commands in [2] are globally accessible, e.g. in [3], and also find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED) works like it should and adds the version suffix.

Comment: Note, that in case of using `include()`, it is better to rename script file into `<...>.cmake`. It is just a naming convention. Non-root `CMakeLists.txt` files are usually parsed with `add_subdirectory()` call.